# Extract time from interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to extract time from an interval row ?

e.g. '1 days 2 hours 30 minutes' and I want to get only '2 hours 30 minutes'

I need this to cast interval to a time row, maybe is there better ways ?

Comment: there is no such thing as an "interval row" or a "time row". Are you confusing "column" with "row"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : sorry, I actually meant field, but I guess column is correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extract`:

```
select extract(hour from interval_column), 
       extract(minute from interval_column)
from the_table
```

If you want convert that to a real `time` value you can use:

```
select make_time(extract(hour from interval_column)::int, 
                 extract(minute from interval_column)::int, 0)
from the_table
```

The above can fail, because an interval *can* contain more then 24 hours. In that case you would need to use `justify_interval` - but it does sound very strange:

```
select make_time(extract(hour from justify_interval(interval_column))::int, 
                 extract(minute from justify_interval(interval_column))::int, 0)
from the_table
```

This would convert `interval '100' hour` into the time `04:00` - whatever you are going to do with that

---

Another option is to add the interval to a time:

```
select time '00:00:00' + interval_column
from the_table
```

Comment: Yeah, the last one is what I needed (how is it strange tho ?)

Comment: @servabat: it's strange because an interval is something completely different then a "time". I don't understand what the logic behind converting a _duration_  ("this took 6 weeks 3 days and 23 hours") into a fixed point in time (it starts at "20:00")

Comment: Actually It's quite tricky, because I import time data from a CSV where hours past midnight are represented with time over 24 hours (e.g. 25:30:00 = 01:30:00).